# How to resize the rotated graph in the graph group in c#?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm using c# GDI+ to write a function for geometric transformation of a graph, but I'm running into a problem. When I use the Scale and rotateAt methods of the Matrix matrix to scale the rotated graph of the same graph group, I have some problems.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

The function I want to achieve is shown in the figure below：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VOXP.png)

Comment: You need to post the code you wrote that fails to achieve the result you're expecting. Also code that explains what a *graph* is and how it's defined in your implementation. -- You skipped the Tour when prompted; see the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) and more specifically [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.